# Selecting correct value in Numpy matrix inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a dataframe with mixed types. I have the columns, x, y, z, matrix, where matrix is a numpy matrix

```
10 10 10 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
12 12 12 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
14 14 14 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to take the value of the matrix in index row 1 column index 1 (5) for plotting together with x, y, z

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
print(df["matrix"][:][1,1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
new = df_max_timestep
tangential_stress = []
for value in df_max_timestep["rotated stress tensor"]:
    tangential_stress.append(value[1,1])
new["Tangential stress"] = tangential_stress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the matrix elements by string accessor `.str[]`, as follows:

```
df['matrix'].str[1].str[1]
```

**Result:**

```
0    5
1    5
2    5
Name: matrix, dtype: int64
```

**Data Setup**

```
data = {'x': [10, 12, 14],
 'y': [10, 12, 14],
 'z': [10, 12, 14],
 'matrix': [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]),
  np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]),
  np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    x   y   z                             matrix
0  10  10  10  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
1  12  12  12  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
2  14  14  14  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @AsbjoernLund  It's weird.  String accessor should be able to access list elements even when the data aren't strings.  What version of Pandas you use ?

Comment: Maybe its because im using a np.matrix and not a np.array?

Comment: @AsbjoernLund  See the [official doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) of np.matrix, : **It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.**     Better use regular np.array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can first `stack` the arrays. Then you will be able to then handle them as numpy arrays:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 10, 10, np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])],
                   [12, 12, 12, np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])],
                   [14, 14, 14, np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])],],
                 columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'matrix']
                 )

np.stack(df['matrix'])[:, 1,1]
```

output:

```
array([5, 5, 5])
```

example of assignment as new column:

```
>>> df['new'] = np.stack(df['matrix'])[:, 1,1]
>>> df
    x   y   z                             matrix  new
0  10  10  10  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]    5
1  12  12  12  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]    5
2  14  14  14  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]    5
```

###### plotting

```
import plotly.express as px

df['matrix_center'] = np.stack(df['matrix'])[:, 1,1]
px.scatter_3d(df, x='x', y='y', z='z', color='matrix_center')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This is not exactly what I want - I want to plot x, y, z and 5 in the matrix as a heatmap, so I need the value to stay in the dataframe

Comment: @AsbjoernLund can you give an example of your plotting command?

Comment: px.scatter_3d(df_max_timestep, x='x', y='y', z='z', color="matrix_center") where matrix_center should be the center value of the matrix.

Comment: I uploaded image of the data structure - the matrix looks messy, but its read correctly as a numpy matrix.

Comment: When I try your code I get: ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.

Comment: @AsbjoernLund if works fine with the example you gave, if you have higher dimensions, then you need to slice the right axis to have a scalar per row. I added an example picture

Comment: Please try my exact dummy example before adapting to your real-life one

Comment: Tested your code - works perfectly! - just not on my data ;-(

Comment: looks like you have higher dimensions in your array, you need to change `[:, 1, 1]` to whatever slicing gives you the scalar you want from one of those arrays

Comment: I can get the value for a single row like this: `print(df["matrix"][0][1,1])`, but if I try `print(df["matrix"][:][1,1])` it gives KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.iloc[0]["matrix"]`

Comment: The correct matrix: `[[-5.08596838e+06  3.61090939e+05  1.55928370e+07]
 [ 3.61090939e+05  1.63390505e+08 -3.93256598e+06]
 [ 1.55928370e+07 -3.93256598e+06 -3.84778200e+07]]`

Comment: I posted a loop that solves the problem - strange the other approach does not work